# How to effect the DropArea with in rootViewer set "Qt::FramelessWindowHint" flag in Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am a newer to Qt. I wanna develop a frameless application. But AreaDrop in QML does not work with the frameless application in Windows.
my code:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: 640
        height: 480
        color: "green"

        DropArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            width: 640
            height: 480
            onEntered: {
                console.log("drop enter")
            }

            onDropped: {
                console.log("droped");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView viewer;
    viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    viewer.setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    viewer.setColor(QColor(Qt::transparent));
    viewer.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

This code works fine in the Ubuntu. But in Windows, the file dropping is unacceptable. I cannot find a solution to resolve this problem.
So, how can I drag a file into the frameless application in Windows.
Thanks!!

Comment: `anchor.fill: parent` means the object is the same size and position as the parent, no need to set width and height additionally.

Comment: `viewer.setColor(QColor(Qt::transparent))` -> `viewer.setColor(Qt::transparent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `QWindow::flags` as set of window flags and (optionally) a set of hints but not only hints. So you have to change

```
viewer.setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

to

```
viewer.setFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

But since you build your GUI in QML I advice you to do that in some way:

```
Window {
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    ...
}
```

And btw avoid setting size since you use anchoring.